# Perform redirect after animation has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript that is used to perform a custom piece of animation.

```
$(function() {
  $('.box .animated.hex-animation').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href= $(this).attr('href');
    $('.box .animated.hex-animation').removeClass('hex-animation').queue(function(){
      $(this).addClass('hex-animation-exit').dequeue();
    }); 
  });
});
```

I have a working sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gy7fpqpf/27/).

I am looking to redirect the browser to the url in the anchor tag after the animation has completed.

Is someone able to advise how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact CSS3 event I needed for this to work is `webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend`. Thanks to kiranvj for pointing me in the right direction. The following code yielded the result I needed.

```
$(function() {
  $('.box .animated.hex-animation').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.box:last .animated.hex-animation:last').one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',   
    function(e) {
      window.location.href = href;
    });
    $('.box .animated.hex-animation').removeClass('hex-animation').queue(function(){
      $(this).addClass('hex-animation-exit').dequeue();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the CSS3 transition end event

```
$('.box .animated.hex-animation').on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',   
    function(e) {

    window.location.href = "Your new url";

  });
```

Comment: I have multiple elements that match that selector as per the sample link. How would this work given that I want the redirect to happen after the animated has executed on the last element that matches the selector?

Comment: @tkha007 Try `$('.box .animated.hex-animation').last().on(...)`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to yield the result I'm after. I've added it to the sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gy7fpqpf/27/) with a simple alert but it doesn't appear to work.